# spec failed. NoMethodError: undefined method `callback' for #<RSpec::ExampleGroups::O

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec-rails, shoulda-matchers

I want to run callbacks. I have added

```
   gem 'shoulda-callback-matchers'
   gem 'shoulda-matchers'
```

in gem file.
My code for callbacks is

```
  describe "#callbacks" do
    it { is_expected.to callback(:set_data).before(:validation) }
    it { is_expected.to callback(:assign_default_to_price).before(:save) }
    it { is_expected.to callback(:set_date).before(:create) }
```

This code snippet utilizes the 'shoulda-callback-matchers' gem to test the expected behavior of callbacks in my code. The callback matcher checks if the specified callbacks (set_data, assign_default_to_price, set_date) are triggered at the correct points (before(:validation), before(:save), before(:create) respectively) in  application's.

All the spec of callback is failing. I am getting error message. One of them is shown below.

```
Test#callbacks 
     Failure/Error: it { is_expected.to callback(:set_date).before(:create) }
     
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `callback' for #<RSpec::ExampleGroups::Order::Callbacks "example at ./spec/models/test_spec.rb:109">**
```

I tried to update gem but no luck. I wrote manual method and its pass my test. read docs and check configuration add `config.include(Shoulda::Callback::Matchers::ActiveModel)` in spec_helper. still not working.

My ruby version is `3.2.2` and rails `6.0`.

Comment: *"add `config.include(Shoulda::Callback::Matchers::ActiveModel)` in `spec_helper`. Still not working."* --- Does the top of this spec file contain `include 'spec_helper'`? What happens if you `include Shoulda::Callback::Matchers::ActiveModel` directly in the spec file?

Comment: @TomLord An error occurred while loading ./spec/models/test_spec.rb.
Failure/Error: config.include(Shoulda::Callback::Matchers::ActiveModel)



`
NameError:
  uninitialized constant Shoulda::Callback
`

Comment: I'm confused. Are you saying the error message is now different, despite not having changed anything? That error seems to imply you're removed the dependency fro the `Gemfile`, but you can also see what needs to be (and should already automatically) be included load that constant [here](https://github.com/jdliss/shoulda-callback-matchers/blob/master/lib/shoulda/callback/matchers/integrations/rspec.rb).